# Java Local Block Yield Value

Tags: java, syntax

Is it possible in Java (17) to somehow create local blocks that return/yield some value to the parent block?

E.g.

```
public void calceSomething(int a, intb) {
  int c = {
    var aSquare = Math.pow(a, 2);
    var bSquare = Math.pow(b, 2);
    var cSquare = aSquare + bSquare;
    yield Math.root(cSuare);
  };
  /* lets further do something with c */
}
```

Comment: What is the use case that justifies not doing this in a method?

Comment: you can use a `switch` expression, but very ugly, confusing, and why? `int c = switch (1) { default -> { ... yield x; } }` (or similar like swap the case and default, )

Comment: ((even `switch ("dummy") ...` or, to make it more confusing:  `switch(c) ...`)) -- `yield` AFAIK is only available inside a switch expression - Java Language Specification [14.21. The yield Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21): "**It is a compile-time error if a yield statement has no yield target.**"

Comment: *inspired* by WJS' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76962371/16320675), you can also use an anonymous object: `var calc = new Object() { int it(...) { ... return result;} }; int c = calc.it(...);` - Warning: only works when using `var` -- `Object calc = new ...` will not work!

Comment: This is a question for possible language feature like this, not any workaround or hacks. Thanks anyways for your suggestions!

Comment: It would be useful to have such a language feature to be able to access all the variables from the parent scope without introducing a new method with lots of parameters. Also it should be type safe regarding exception handling. Also the inner variables should only be available inside the block and not afterwards.

Comment: well, maybe the question was posted to soon to make it clear of that... "*somehow create local blocks*" kind of sounds like searching some hack/workaround... BTW the inner object kind of has access to the variables of the *parent*, but if you just *need* access to the variables and inner variables only available inside, a normal block will do: `int c; { ... c = ...; }` - not sure what exactly is meant by safe regarding exception handling...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"... Is it possible in Java (17) to somehow create local blocks that return/yield some value to the parent block? ..."*

No, this is not part of the syntax.  I believe the recommendation is to create a method or a class.

You *could* utilize the closure framework, and implement an interface.
*[Lambda Expressions (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Classes and Objects)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)*.

```java
interface Hypotenuse {
    double calculate(int a, int b);
}
```

```java
void hypotenuse(int a, int b) {
    double c = ((Hypotenuse) (x, y) -> {
        var aSquare = Math.pow(x, 2);
        var bSquare = Math.pow(y, 2);
        var cSquare = aSquare + bSquare;
        return Math.sqrt(cSquare);
    }).calculate(a, b);
}
```

You could even add the *interface* to the method.

```java
void hypotenuse(int a, int b) {
    interface Hypotenuse { double calculate(int a, int b); }
    double c = ((Hypotenuse) (x, y) -> {
        var aSquare = Math.pow(x, 2);
        var bSquare = Math.pow(y, 2);
        var cSquare = aSquare + bSquare;
        return Math.sqrt(cSquare);
    }).calculate(a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not literally like you posted, but, given that there is no point to such a construct *other than* trying to espouse a certain effect on the 'structure' (how it looks / how the experience of that reads the code goes), I guess what you're really asking for, is: Can I make something that his this *structure*.

And then answer is trivially yes, but it does play havoc with auto-formatter rules because they aren't designed with this 'style' in mind.

This is perfectly valid java, and has been for 30 years; no need for new java versions, even (well, I'll use your `var` which was introduced in java 10):

```
int c; {
  var aSquare = Math.pow(a, 2);
  var bSquare = Math.pow(b, 2);
  var cSquare = aSquare + bSquare;
  c = Math.root(cSquare);
}
```

Yes, that's legal. There are some funky things happening here:

- Yes, that's a statement (`int c;`), then a *space*, then just.. a block. It's legal to just start blocks for no reason in java.
- The `aSquare`, `bSquare`, and `cSquare` variable names are scoped to this 4-liner block; the variables poof out of existence immediately after that closing brace, so you aren't 'infecting' the outer scope with these variables and if you write another such block later in in the same method, you can again use the name `aSquare`, which would have absolutely no relationship whatsoever with *this* `aSquare`variable.
- After the block, the `c` variable has the states 'definitely assigned', as well as 'effectively final', which are both good things.
- Every auto-formatter tool I know of would stick a newline after `int c;` and then stick the opening brace of the block on its own line. However, that's.. just your auto-formatter doing that. Java-the-lang-spec doesn't require this, and written like it is above, the *intent* of that code is much more clear (namely, that the block's function is to calculate a value for c. That's the only thing it does). I don't auto-format my code. Instead I format it properly as I type. It's a habit that is effortless and has advantages (such as letting me write the above), but I can't tell you how much retraining it would take or if everybody is inclined to it; I've been doing it for decades at this point, so I can't give meaningful insights in how one would learn it now.

Alternatives on the theme are this style:

```
public void foo() {
  /* description of a helpery task */ {
    code that does the thing
  }
}
```

This can be better than an actual helper method in the sense that you don't need to parameterize all the context you require in this 'helper block'. You can go real nuts and use labels if you must. This is legal:

```
public void foo() {
  helperyTaskDescription: {
    calculations_go_here();
    if (reasonToStop) break helperyTaskDescription;
    more_calculations();
  }
}
```

You must 'label' the break or it doesn't work, but that is effectively 'go to closing brace of the block labelled helperyTaskDescription'. You can use this style even if you don't actually break to it, though lots of linter tools will then complain about an unused label. If you find it looks great and it helps readability, there's a big caveat here in general: Writing code in a style few java programmers are familiar with has downsides - your code will be harder to share. But you have to weigh that against the benefits of tightly scoped variable names and the like.

If the question isn't about good code style and just about a pedantic/academic point to be made, I'm no sure that's a good way to spend your time, but, if you must, you can introduce a pointless switch block just for the privilege of making `yield` do a thing:

```
int c = switch (0) {
  default -> {
    var aSquare = Math.pow(a, 2);
    var bSquare = Math.pow(b, 2);
    var cSquare = aSquare + bSquare;
    yield Math.root(cSquare);
  }
}
```

Looks pretty bad and that's a lot of boilerplate, and it really needs a comment because I bet the vast majority of java coders who see that will immediately be focussing on what the heck the switch is doing here and therefore require a comment explaining: *I really just wanted to be able to `yield` and I was willing to accept this disaster to do it.*

NB: Just to be thorough - very often the stylistically preferrably answer is to just make helper methods. `int c = deviation(a, b);` is probably the 'right' way to do this. This doesn't just make the code itself easier to read (now you just mentally grok what 'deviation' means and can simplify your understanding of the code, replacing the 4 lines you have with just 'deviation between a and b'), *and* it lets you optimize. For example, it is likely that `Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b)` is a significantly better way to do this. With a helper method you only have one place to make a change instead of search-replacing loads of code. However, not *every situation* where you want a block to 'group' the code together *and* tightly scope any local vars you declare, is best tackled with a helper method. Just - this specific example you wrote probably is!

Comment: But in your first approach `c` is not final. Therefore I can not use it in lambdas, right

Comment: It also might happen, that the programmer forgets to assign a value to c inside the block. This should be covered by the compiler IMO

Comment: @andi If a variable is only assigned once (`int c;` is only a declaration, not an assignment), then the variable is _effectively final_. That means it can be used inside lambdas. And if you don't definitely assign `c` before trying to use it then you will get a compiler error.

Comment: @andi Yes, you __can__ use `c` in lambdas! Use in lambdas doesn't _require_ a `final` keyword (but you can make `c` `final` here if you want, it'll compile fine!) - merely that if you _would_ stick `final` on it, that it would compile (i.e. the compiler will infer it for you if needed). This is called _effectively final_. And, yes, `c` is effectively final _and_ definitely assigned which are 2 the two necessary and sufficient properties to use a local in a lambda.

Comment: @andi `final` doesn't require that it is assigned. You can declare a final variable and fail to initialize it (`final int c;`), this is fine. The compiler will check that all possible code paths only assign a value to `c` at most once, and will disallow any attempt to use `c` unless every code path that gets you there will have assigned it at least once.

Comment: And, yes, if someone fails to assign a value to `c`, _and_ you actually use `c` later, the compiler will refuse to compile the code and will mark off the place where c is read as: Nope - c isn't definitely assigned in here, so you can't do that. Sounds like it's what you want, no?

Comment: @rzwitserloot it is definitly the nearest what I am looking for. Thanks a lot for the answers and explainations!